Adjusting Flexipage Bottom Margin for Hidden LWC Component on Salesforce App Page
I’m working with a Salesforce LWC component attached to an app page, where I need to control its show/hide behavior. However, I’m encountering an issue where a small space remains above the component even when it’s hidden.
I’ve identified that this issue is caused by the bottom margin of the Flexipage. I attempted to set the Flexipage’s bottom margin to zero by using this.template.querySelector with the component’s data ID, like this:
const element = this.template.querySelector('[data-component-id="myComponentId"]');
if (element) {
    element.style.marginBottom = '0px';
}

Unfortunately, this approach didn’t work. I also tried several CSS solutions, but they weren’t effective.
Is there a way to adjust the margin of this component using JavaScript? Or if there’s any other approach to solve this issue, please let me know.
